# Get Usercontrol which inherits Type X using reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection

Given this usercontrol ascx in a web application:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="TypeX" Codebehind="TypeX.ascx.cs" %>
```

Is it possible to use reflection to get the usercontrol when I start with:

```
Type targetType = typeof(TypeX);
... now what? to code to get the usercontrol
```

I have tried to use:

```
assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(targetType))
```

but this does not give any result.

Any help appreciated

EXTRA INFO:

The codebehind (simplified) is:

```
 public partial class TypeX : UserControlBase
{
}

//we use this control:
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="Loadcontrol " Codebehind="Loadcontrol .ascx.cs" %>
//with this codebehind
 public partial class Loadcontrol 
{
    OnPrerender()
    {
        string controlToLoad = "TypeX";
        //what to do here
    }

}
```

I hope it is more clear now

UPDATE: I have made an example webapplication to show the problem.
The download can be found at: [WebApplication1.zip](http://filedump.org/files/9VJxLgAy1346247487.html) or use: [Download mirror](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/19803636/WebApplication1.zip)

Answer (score 0):

```
Type targetType = typeof(TypeX);
var control = Page.LoadControl(targetType, null);
```

You need to use this code in a page.

Comment: The problem is: I am the baseclass of TypeX which is NOT in the page. So i can't use LoadControl there... can I?

Comment: I see you're in a user control. You can use LoadControl from the Page property

Comment: When I do this I don't get the same result as:
Page.LoadControl("<path to control>.ascx").

Comment: When I use Page.LoadControl(targetType, null); i get a control with the type of the codebehind, so without all the knowledge of the markup in the ascx. Whe I use Page.LoadControl("<path to control>.ascx") I get the type WITH all controls from the markup in the ascx

Comment: How do you distinct between to results?

Comment: loading by controlname gives me: ASP.TypeX_ascx as result. loading by Type gives me TypeX as result

Comment: Don't you get a control instance as result?

Comment: No, I get the underlying type, not the control itself

Comment: Very strange. Didn't happen to me. Add your full code and I'll try it.

Comment: Indeed it is not working. Still I didn't understand why don't you use the control path.

Comment: Because that is the unknown in my actual project. All I know is the Type of the codebehind file

Comment: Consider opening the aspx files and search for the one corresponds to the cs file. When you find it you know the path.